# React Native Buttons onPress nothing happens, also onChangeText not working

Tags: react-native, routes, expo, react-native-paper

I am new to React Native. I have a single login form with two fields. I want to authenticate the user before sending him to Dashboard.js. No matter what I try the button is not doing anything(absolutely nothing happens,no error). I have kept the code in Login.js to show all the things I have tried to do namely

1. routing to dashboard.js
2. trying to do something with invoking the handleSubmitPress function on button press.
3. pop an alert.

I have used two buttons. One from react-native-paper and one from react-native.
I am giving the code of my app.js and login.js below. Please can someone help?

CODE

```
  App.js
    import React from "react";
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
    import DashBoard from "./mainmenu/DashBoard";
    import Login from "./mainmenu/Login";
    
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            <Stack.Screen name="DashBoard" component={DashBoard} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
    
    
    Login.js
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Title, TextInput} from "react-native-paper";
    import { View, Alert,Button } from "react-native";
    export default function Login() {
      const [mobile, setMobile] = useState("123456789");
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("123");
    
      function handleSubmitPress() {
        console.log({ mobile, password });
      }
    
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "skyblue",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
          }}
        >
          <TextInput
            label="Your mobile number "
            value={mobile}
            onChangeText={(text) => setMobile(text)}
          />
          <TextInput
            label="Type Password  "
            value={password}
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          />
    
          <Button
            icon="camera"
            type="submit"
            mode="contained"
            //onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("DashBoard")}
            onPress={()=>Alert.alert('Navigate pressed')}
          >
            Navigate
          </Button>
    
          <Button
              title="Print"
              onPress={() => Alert.alert('Simple Button pressed')}
              // onPress={handleSubmitPress()}
            />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Login component to this.

```
...
const Login = ({navigation}) => {
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('123456789');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('123');

  function handleSubmitPress() {
    console.log({mobile, password});
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      <TextInput
        label="Your mobile number "
        value={mobile}
        onChangeText={text => setMobile(text)}
      />
      <TextInput
        label="Type Password  "
        value={password}
        onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
      />

      <Button
        title="title"
        icon="camera"
        type="submit"
        mode="contained"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DashBoard')}>
        Navigate
      </Button>

      <Button title="Print" onPress={() => handleSubmitPress()} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

There were a couple problems.

I've used the default React Native buttons. So I added a title prop to one of the buttons, because that's required. I gave it the value "title", but change this to what you want or use the React Native Paper buttons.

The main problem was how you called `handleSubmitPress` in your button `onPress`.

Your `onChangeText` was fine, you just couldn't see the result, because the `handleSubmitPress` wasn't being called.

I've also used destructuring so you're able to access the navigation prop directly. You can also do `const Long = (props) => {...}` and use `props.navigation`, but either way you need to pass in something otherwise navigation will not work.